# Regression Proposal for project with zero testing documentation

Tags: regression-testing, manual-testing

I recently started a project in which all testing has been done with zero documentation.  I need to start creating a Regression suite and propose it to my manager.  I have done regression testing earlier, but I have never put together such a document.  What do I absolutely need to include and what should I include, any tips or templates would help greatly.

Answer (score 2):

The other suggestions here are good ones.

Some additional thoughts from my experience:

- Format matters less than content: if you and your manager have something you can work with, you have enough to start with.
- You don't want to try to cover everything from the start. You're new to the project: you don't have enough context to cover everything.
- Your first priority for regression is the critical functionality and anything you need to access the critical functionality (in other words, don't sweat log on/log off - you'll cover that while you're testing critical functions for your customers).
- Start with a high level description of the functionality you're looking at: "non-taxed transactions" might be an example. Or "delete a product". You can always add more information.
- For manual regression, I recommend keeping it as light and simple as you possibly can. Humans get tired and lose focus no matter how dedicated they are.
- You will need to know the most used configuration settings. These will be the core of your manual regression tests.
- Long term, look to identify potential automation candidates and potential expanded regression candidates.
- You want to work towards a multi-tier regression suite:

  - a short regression smoke test that covers the most critical items (manual)
  - a longer manual regression suite that can be used when there's a need in a particularly fragile part of the system
  - a set of automated regression suites run on a regular basis that you expect to always pass and are continually monitoring to make sure they're still relevant and are constantly adding new tests to.
  - a set of specialized automation regression suites that may require a very long run-time but provide exhaustive checking of crucial parts of the system (such as tax calculations). These can be used when the calculation engines change.

Answer (score 0):

some good ideas can be found in [37 Sources for Test Ideas](http://thetesteye.com/posters/TheTestEye_SourcesForTestIdeas.pdf)

some highlights- look for similar products and similarities in other products, what are the business needs and goals, official standards and de facto standards, and most important think like a user.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, there is no definite answer to that. The task you have is quite creative and you will have to improvise but here are few thoughts:

- Start with some essential and common features like login/logout, reset password, user registration etc. and add them to the regression suite.
- Talk to the people in your team, especially product people. Try to determine what are the essential user journeys in your product, go through them and create tests cases
- If that's possible, try to look at the bugs history for the project to see where most of the critical/high priority bugs occur